# How to make join on boost::asio::io_service?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, threadpool

Here is the problem:

In the main thread (io - boost::asio::io_service):

```
io.post(functor1, callback1)
....
io.post(functorN, callbackN)

io.join() <--- waiting while all the task to be processed and continue to execute the program
```

The code is executed in a loop. `boost::thread_group` would perfectly match, but it creates new threads all the times, while I want to create working threads only once and dispatch tasks to them, exactly as asio does. All pool threads I've seen are just wrapers around vector of threads + io_service, it can't be used in the way I've shown above.

So, how can I make "join" for boost::asio?

Comment: How are you running work in the io service queue? Using run() or poll()? Do you use any io_service::work objects?

Comment: I use ``work``. I create few threads by ``thread_group`` and call ``run()`` inside every working thread.

Answer (score 1):

So,

```
work_.reset();
thread_group_.join_all();
```

should be enough. The usual approach is to have

```
boost::unique_ptr<io_service::work> work_; // non-copyable
```

or

```
boost::optional<io_service::work> work_; // copyable
```